# Azure Databricks Autoloader schema check does not recognize when a column is removed from schema

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-autoloader

My team is writing a streaming application to load files into our data lake.  Our environment is Azure, we are using spark and databricks for the application.  It is a streaming application to read mostly csv files with a set schema.  We are using Autoloader to facilitate reading the files from their directories.  It is important that we are able to note when a schema changes, hence the decision to use autoloader.  During testing of the application, when a file schema has a new column added or a column is renamed it recognizes the change.  However, when a column is dropped from a file the schema mismatch is not noted and the missing column is set to null in the stream.  This might be an edge case, but there is a slim probability we could see this.  Is there a way to get autoloader to identify missing schema columns in a file or a way within a readStream to recognize when a file schema devolves?

We have tried using cloudFiles inferschema with different settings and adding the schema to the readStream.

Comment: Excellent question - the link https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/schema.html#how-does-auto-loader-schema-evolution-work only mentions about addition of new columns, but not the other way around...But on the other hand lakehouses or warehouses are typically all about data addition and never deletion...usually versioned out...anyways hope there is a solution...